# AttributeError, What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I have a program that I cannot call to run, where I try to call the linearSearch() def from spellCheck.py. Can someone help me understand why my code gives me a AttributeError? I do not understand why when calling initial.linearSearch(choice) won't give me anything.

spellCheck.py:

```
class SpellCheck():
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            open("dictionary.txt", "r")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Dictionary file not found")
        else:
            #store all elements in a list 
            dictionary = []
            #open dictionary.txt
            with open("dictionary.txt", "r") as f:
                for line in f:
                    dictionary.append(line.strip())
        def binarySearch(self, word):
            steps = 0
            low = 0
            high = len(dictionary) - 1
            while low <= high:
                middle = (low + high) // 2
                if(dictionary[middle] == word):
                    steps += 1
                    return (f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}Found {bcolors.BOLD}{word}{bcolors.ENDC}{bcolors.OKGREEN} after {steps} steps!{bcolors.ENDC}")
                elif (dictionary[middle] < word):
                    steps += 1
                    low = middle + 1
                else:
                    steps += 1
                    high = middle - 1
            return(f"{bcolors.FAIL}The word {bcolors.BOLD}{word}{bcolors.ENDC}{bcolors.FAIL} wasn't found!{bcolors.ENDC}")

        def linearSearch(word):
            steps = 0
            for i in range(len(dictionary)):
                steps += 1
                if dictionary[i] == self.word:
                    steps += 1
                    return(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}Found {bcolors.BOLD}{self.word}{bcolors.ENDC}{bcolors.OKGREEN} after {steps - 1} steps!{bcolors.ENDC}")
            return(f"{bcolors.FAIL}The word {bcolors.BOLD}{self.word}{bcolors.ENDC}{bcolors.FAIL} wasn't found!{bcolors.ENDC}")

#color coding for terminal
#source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/287944
#either True or False
class bcolors:
        BOLD = '\033[1m'
        OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
        FAIL = '\033[91m'
        ENDC = '\033[0m'
        YELLOW = '\033[93m'
        #debug statement
        #if debug == True:
            #print(f"Debug Colors:\n{BOLD}BOLD{ENDC}\n{OKGREEN}OKGREEN{ENDC}\n{FAIL}FAIL{ENDC}\n{YELLOW}YELLOW{ENDC}")
    #end of color codes
```

main.py

```
from spellCheck import SpellCheck
#from spellCheck import bcolors

def main():
    choice = input("Enter the word to look for:\n> ")
    initial = SpellCheck()
    initial.__init__()
    initial.linearSearch(choice)
    
    
main()
```

Here is the output of the terminal:

```
Enter the word to look for:
> apple
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 8, in main
    initial.linearSearch(choice)
AttributeError: 'SpellCheck' object has no attribute 'linearSearch'
```

Comment: Your functions are defined `__init__` and aren't properties of the class. Unindent those functions

Comment: 1. `__init__` is called when you create the object in `initial = SpellCheck()`. 2. all you class functions are indented too much and are instead defined inside `__init__`.

Comment: More than that you shouldn't call __init__ after you already write SpellCheck(). __init__ will be called automatically when you create instance of SpellCheck class

Comment: You could try an IDE like PyCharm or VS code. Both are free, but VS code needs more configuration. It will help you by marking your errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`binarySearch(self, word)` and `linearSearch(word)` are the functions of `__init__`

that's why you are not getting any error on `initial.linearSearch(choice)`.

If you want them to be separate functions of `SpellCheck()` then unindent them.